# Where can we get the liferay Iframe portlet source code?

Tags: iframe, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I need to a portlet to access the remote applications. So I need the Iframe type portlet. I have tested the I frame on liferay portal. I need the source code of the Iframe portlet, so that I need to customize it as required and ddeploy the same on to portal. I tried to get the Iframe portlet source code but I didn't get any proper budle with full souce code. Can any one suggest me that where can I download full Iframe portlet source code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IFrame portlet is a Liferay core portlet and therefore it's source can be found in the liferay src.

Liferay Source can be downloaded from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/

You will find the IFrame's frontend in package: portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/iframe/

and backend in package: portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/iframe/

Comment: Able to find the Iframe's front end. Not clear with backend path